# how to pass quoted sexp to macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, quote

I have a function that replaces all instances of a symbol in a list:

```
(defun replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn (symbol-to-replace new-symbol sexp)
  (if (eq sexp nil)
      sexp
      (cons
       (if (listp (car sexp))
           (replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn symbol-to-replace new-symbol (car sexp))
           (if (eq (car sexp) symbol-to-replace)
               (setf (car sexp) new-symbol)
               (car sexp)))
       (replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn symbol-to-replace new-symbol (cdr sexp)))))

(defmacro replace-symbol-in-sexp (symbol-to-replace new-symbol sexp)
  `(replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn ,symbol-to-replace ,new-symbol ,sexp))

(macroexpand-1 (replace-symbol-in-sexp '+ '* (+ 2 3)))
; => TYPE-ERROR "The value 5 is not of type LIST" if sexp has comma,
; => UNBOUND-VARIABLE "The variable SEXP is unbound" if sexp has no comma
```

I'm getting either a type error or an undefined-variable error when attempting to evaluate the final expression, depending upon whether sexp is comma'd or not in the last line. I've tested and replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn works when given, say:

```
(replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn '+ '* '(+ 2 3)) ; => (* 2 3)
```

I'm trying to now produce this with a macro so that the sexp doesn't have to be quoted like `'(+ 2 3)`, and so I can run replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn with arbitrary lisp code. Obviously, I could eval and pass in a sexp quoted to replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn, like:

```
(eval (replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn '+ '* '(+ 2 3))
```

But that's a clunky attempt to imitate macros, so I'd prefer to actually just use a macro. Is there a clean way to do what I'm trying to do with macros? What am I missing?

Comment: "I'm getting either a type error or an undefined-variable error"  I don't see either of these in the question. Can you show an example?

Comment: Edited with precise results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you reimplemented the Common Lisp function [nsubst](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_substc.htm). `subst` is the normal version and `n` indicates that it is the destructive version (non-consing).

Note that in portable Common Lisp it is not a good idea to modify literal data. The effects are undefined. Ignoring that for a while:

```
(macroexpand-1 (replace-symbol-in-sexp '+ '* (+ 2 3)))
```

But probably you wanted to macroexpand the expression and not the result? Probably should be:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(replace-symbol-in-sexp '+ '* (+ 2 3)))
```

But that macro makes no sense. The generated code is false, since the last argument does not evaluate to a list. The macro has to create useful code. As you see the last expression is unquoted, which make no sense.

```
CL-USER 14 > (macroexpand-1 '(replace-symbol-in-sexp '+ '* (+ 2 3)))
(REPLACE-SYMBOL-IN-SEXP-FN (QUOTE +) (QUOTE *) (+ 2 3))
```

Let's introduce a quote:

```
(defmacro replace-symbol-in-sexp (symbol-to-replace new-symbol sexp)
   `(replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn ,symbol-to-replace ,new-symbol ',sexp))

CL-USER 17 > (macroexpand-1 '(replace-symbol-in-sexp '+ '* (+ 2 3)))
(REPLACE-SYMBOL-IN-SEXP-FN (QUOTE +) (QUOTE *) (QUOTE (+ 2 3)))
```

Is that macro useful? I have my doubts.

Comment: This was helpful; I didn't realize I could stick a quote before a comma like that.

What are your doubts on its utility?

Comment: @cosmicexplorer I can't speak for sure, but I expect that Rainer's point was that **replace-symbol-in-sexp** probably isn't all that useful, since it is, as Rainer pointed out, essentially **subst** or **nsubst**.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor what would be a macro which just adds a quote to the third argument useful for? Why not use the function directly?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Oy, that's an even better point.  I just latched on to the first thing that you mentioned.  Yeah, a macro that could just as easily be a function isn't very useful either (and especially when the function already exists).

Comment: A macro shifts the subst to compile time, which seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: @cosmicexplorer: Macros *can* shift execution to compile time, but not your macro. There is nothing in your macro that executes the code at compile time. It does not do anything useful at compile time.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I'm aware of that. I'm simply stating that as the motivation for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not want to expand to the function invocation, but use the function to expand your code.  You should not quote it then:

```
(defmacro replace-symbol-in-sexp (symbol-to-replace new-symbol sexp)
  (replace-symbol-in-sexp-fn symbol-to-replace new-symbol sexp))
```

I have the impression that you are just trying to re-implement something like [`symbol-macrolet`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_symbol.htm).

Comment: Well, it was more that I didn't know there was already a function for these sorts of things, since when I searched "replace symbol in sexp" I couldn't find a reference to those things in the CLHS.